# Accessing null keys in maps with EL

Tags: jsf, el

I have a `Map<Person, Map<String, Integer> >` that can contain a `null` `Person` key. This is intended.

In my JSF page:

```
<ui:repeat var="svc" value="#{bean.services}">
  <ui:repeat var="person" value="#{bean.people}">
    <h:outputText value="#{bean.byPerson[person][svc]}" /> <!-- Returns nothing/blank -->
    <h:outputText value="#{bean.byPerson.get(person)[svc]}" />  <!-- Works, returns number -->
  </ui:repeat>
</ui:repeat>
```

When `person` is `null`, `value="#{bean.byPerson[person][svc]}"` does not work (nothing comes back/blank), but  `value="#{bean.byPerson.get(person)[svc]}"` works as expected - it returns the Integer value.

No exceptions are thrown.

Is this a bug in EL or is it by design?